# How to add grand total column to pivot grid

Tags: devexpress

I'm using devexpress 12.1.5 version.

I need to add 2nd grand total column and row to my pivot grid. 
1st grand total is ok. It counts total sum and i need 2nd grand total column and rows to show percentage of this values.

I tried to add another field with same values and only showed grand total values, but Previous field doesn't show. So, I think, I need to add 2nd grand total to original field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From: [Custom PivotGrid Grand total](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q334031)

> You can use the [PivotGridControl.CustomSummary](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraPivotGridPivotGridControl_CustomSummarytopic) event to
>   accomplish this task. Please refer to the [How to provide custom
>   summary values for Total, Grand Total and ordinary cells](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/p/E2592.aspx) example
>   demonstrating how to provide custom values only for Grand Total cells.

Refer these:
[Custom Summaries](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/CustomDocument7301)
[Grand Totals](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#windowsforms/CustomDocument1900)
[PivotGrid and calculate Custom Grand total based on other Grand Total](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q489564)
[Devexpress Pivotgrid: How to define custom summary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22665053/devexpress-pivotgrid-how-to-define-custom-summary)